# ng2-tooltip-directive hide tooltip on mousemove event

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-tooltip-directive

I want to hide tooltip on mouseenter event. How I am able to achieve that?

```
<div
  (mousemove)="closeTooltip()"

  [tooltip]="TooltipComponent" 
  content-type="template"  
  show-delay="500" 
  placement="right"  
  theme="light"
>


<ng-template #TooltipComponent>
  <app-tooltip-wrapper [data]="currentData"></app-tooltip-wrapper>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but it looks like you're trying to both show and hide the tooltip at the same time. Hovering over the div with the tooltip directive will show the tooltip. At the same time the mousemove event would close the tooltip. So the tooltip would never show

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to set hide delay after click ,It default value is 2000 and you can set it below "300" ms and it will hide on click.

```
]hideDelayAfterClick]="'300'"
```

[click here to view ng-tooltip doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tooltip-directive)